# Pass immutable variable with inout

Tags: swift, constants, inout

I create an object in ContentView of a class and pass it to a function

```
@StateObject var portfolio = Portfolio()

...

///Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: 'portfolio' is a get-only property
setCoin(portfolio: &portfolio, currencyList: currencyList, currency: currency, quantity: quantity)

...

func setCoin(portfolio:inout Portfolio, currencyList: [String : Int], currency: String, quantity: String){

    for coin in portfolio.coins{
        if coin.name == currency{
            //Cannot assign to property: 'coin' is a 'let' constant
            coin.quantity = Double(quantity)
            portfolio.portfolioList.append(coin)
        }
    }
}
```

portfolio.coins is an array of objects obtained from a JSON decoding. I am attempting to add a quantity variable that is user input to use in views.

Answer (score 0):

`Portfolio` is **reference** type. And `inout` is for **value** types.

Just pass the reference

```
func setCoin(portfolio: Portfolio, currencyList: [String : Int], currency: String, quantity: String){
```

Edit: To modify `coins` which is apparently a value type array you have to use `enumerated()` and modify the item in the array directly by index

```
for (index, coin) in portfolio.coins.enumerated() {
    if coin.name == currency {
        portfolio.coins[index].quantity = Double(quantity)
        portfolio.portfolioList.append(portfolio.coins[index])
    }
}
```

I highly recommend to move the last line in the loop - actually the entire logic - into the model

Comment: The coin.quantity assignment still produces an error "Cannot assign to property: 'coin' is a 'let' constant" after removing the inout and &. I had added getters and setters for the Coin struct but that didn't solve the issue. Thank you for the response

Comment: coin is let declared as let because that is how a for each loop works so you would need to create a local variable inside the loop, `var temp = coin` and then use it instead. If you ask me though then I think you are doing this backwards, instead of having this function in your view (?) you should have a function in Portfolio that takes a currency and a quantity as arguments and then that function handles the updates